# How to solve 404 error in ngnix using node.js

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean

I am new to `node.js` and `digital ocean`. I created one project in node.js and hosted it on a digital ocean server. While it works properly in http server, I have a problem after changing it to a https server.

The index page loads fine (`https://ap.locals`), but the login page (`https://ao.locals/login`) gives a 404 error.

The https server was created using `ngnix`. What could the problem be?

Comment: Can you post your config file?

Comment: ap || ao? is it typo?

Comment: i am using  https://ap.locals/login

Comment: server {
           listen        80;
          listen        [::]:80;
        server_name   myDomainName.com;
        root          /www/html;

        

        location /{
            proxy_pass "http://www.myDomainName.com:8080";
        }

    }

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ap.locals/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ap.locals/privkey.pem;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/ap.locals.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/ap.locals.error.log;

    server_name _;

    root            /var/www/html;

    index           index.html;

    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json;

    location /.well-known/ {
        try_files   $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location / {
        include             /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_pass          http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_read_timeout  90s;
        proxy_redirect      http://localhost:8080 https://ap.locals;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have same configuration file.but still i am getting 404 error

Comment: the only other thing that I can think of is calling "systemctl reload nginx" after changing the config to use proxy_redirect. don't know

Comment: i have .jade files and that files are kept in views folder